# How to filter entries from a list of dataframes based on multiple criteria in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filtering, subset

I would like to filter 'similar' entries from a list in R. The input list follows:

```
d1=data.frame(y1 = c('Mike'),
              y2 = c('Tsoutsa'),
              y3 = c('Apple'),
              time = 50)

d2=data.frame(y1 = c('Mike'),
              y2 = c('Tsoutsa'),
              y3 = c('Orange'),
              time = 160)

d3=data.frame(y1 = c('Mike'),
              y2 = c('Tsoutsa'),
              y3 = c('Lemon'),
              time = 100)

d4=data.frame(y1 = c('Anna'),
              y2 = c('Pournova'),
              y3 = c('Nikolief'),
              time = 30)

d5=data.frame(y1 = c('Anna'),
              y2 = c('Pournova'),
              y3 = c('Leeds'),
              y4 = c('York'),
              time = 80 )

d6=data.frame(y1 = c('Loulis'),
              y2 = c('City'),
              time = 200 )

d7=data.frame(y1 = c('Ann'),
              y2 = c('Klitor'),
              time = 200 )

input = list(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7)
```

In the output list I would like to keep only the dataframes that have unique `y1` and `y2` values. If there are dataframes with same `y1` and `y2` then keep the one with the highest `time`.
Hence, the output list should be:  `output = list(d2, d5, d6, d7)`.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can bind the rows (dplyr::bind_rows, with `.id` argument to create an identifier), and for `y1` and `y2` group, you can select the one with max time, then extract the set of ids. Use that to index the input list

```
library(dplyr)

retain = as.numeric(bind_rows(input,.id = "d") %>% 
  group_by(y1,y2) %>% 
  slice_max(time) %>%
  pull(d))

output <- input[sort(retain)]
```

An approach using `data.table` is as follows:

```
library(data.table)

input[
  rbindlist(lapply(input, setDT), idcol="d", fill=T)[, .SD[time==max(time)], .(y1,y2)]$d
]
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
    y1      y2     y3 time
1 Mike Tsoutsa Orange  160

[[2]]
    y1       y2    y3   y4 time
1 Anna Pournova Leeds York   80

[[3]]
      y1   y2 time
1 Loulis City  200

[[4]]
   y1     y2 time
1 Ann Klitor  200
```

#### Update 8/23/22

An alternative data.table approach:

```
rbindlist(
  lapply(input, \(i) setDT(i)[, .(y1, y2, time)]), idcol = "d"
)[order(y1,y2,-time),id:=1:.N,.(y1,y2)][id==1]
```

Output:

```
       d     y1       y2  time    id
   <int> <char>   <char> <num> <int>
1:     2   Mike  Tsoutsa   160     1
2:     5   Anna Pournova    80     1
3:     6 Loulis     City   200     1
4:     7    Ann   Klitor   200     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @langtang . Is there a less memory demanding way of doing that? In my case I have 800k small dataframes in my input list and these ways cause some troubles with the 32G RAM. Thanks.

Comment: well, you certainly want to use data.table.. I've adjusted the data.table version which might be less memory-exhaustive.